# Avoid Nested Loop in R

Tags: r

I am going to implement a formula in R. I used the following code although it gave me the right answer it took a lots of time to execute. I am wondering is there any better way to rewrite this piece of code to improve the speed of it. I am going to avoid nested loop but for subtract I could not find an effective one.

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(data)-1))
        {
                for(j in (i+1):nrow(data))
                {


                        A <- - sum((data[i,] - data[j,]) ^ 2)
                        guass.sim [i,j] <-  exp (A / B)

                }
        }
```

Comment: What is your input and desired output?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/KRLS/html/gausskernel.html) or [here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/KRLS/html/gausskernel.html)